# Segfault using xvfb with Gazebo but not with xnest

Tags: ros, gazebo, remote, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I'm trying to get a little further with running Gazebo remotely.

On the remote machine, one display (:1) is provided by Xvfb, while the other (:2) is provided by Xnest.

glxinfo says both displays provide direct rendering.
Xnest works, but Xvfb segfaults

**Any suggestions as to what's happening?**

The remote machine does not have a supported graphics card (yet Xnest works).

The local machine is a mac (running Snow Lepoard) with an nvidia card.

I hope Xvfb is going to be an option because it permits glxgears to operate at 487 FPS vs 4 FPS with Xnest.

*I'm starting with gazebo on electric because this error message is more meaningful than what I see on fuerte (gazebo 1.0.1).*

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe40f5ad5 in Ogre::GLXWindow::create (this=0x7ffff7eb8288, name=..., width=542, height=305, 
    fullScreen=<value optimized out>, miscParams=<value optimized out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp:326
326 /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp: No such file or directory.
    in /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffe40f5ad5 in Ogre::GLXWindow::create (this=0x7ffff7eb8288, name=..., width=542, height=305, 
    fullScreen=<value optimized out>, miscParams=<value optimized out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp:326
#1  0x00007fffe40e84b2 in Ogre::GLXGLSupport::newWindow (this=0x737f60, name=..., width=542, height=305, 
    fullScreen=false, miscParams=0x7fffffffd3f0)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXGLSupport.cpp:379
#2  0x00007fffe40a6a6a in Ogre::GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow (this=0x7ffff7eb7758, name=..., 
    width=542, height=305, fullScreen=false, miscParams=0x7fffffffd3f0)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp:1009
#3  0x00007ffff6e1146f in Ogre::Root::createRenderWindow (this=0x7ffff7ea78d8, 
    name=<value optimized out>, width=<value optimized out>, height=<value optimized out>, 
    fullScreen=<value optimized out>, miscParams=<value optimized out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreRoot.cpp:1199
#4  0x00007ffff5641be7 in gazebo::OgreCreator::CreateWindow(_XDisplay*, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int) () from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_rendering.so
#5  0x00007ffff5642b8d in gazebo::OgreCreator::CreateWindow(Fl_Window*, unsigned int, unsigned int) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_rendering.so
#6  0x00007ffff567b857 in gazebo::UserCamera::UserCamera(gazebo::GLWindow*) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_rendering.so
#7  0x00007ffff58cf43a in gazebo::GLWindow::CreateCameras(double) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_gui.so.0.10.0
#8  0x00007ffff58ddeac in gazebo::GLFrameManager::CreateCameras() ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_gui.so.0.10.0
#9  0x00007ffff7b9155e in gazebo::Simulator::Load(gazebo::XMLConfig*, int) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#10 0x00007ffff7b92292 in gazebo::Simulator::LoadWorldFile(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#11 0x0000000000462864 in main (argc=2, argv=<value optimized out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.15/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/gazeboros.cpp:2581
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36549/segfault-using-xvfb-with-gazebo-but-not-with-xnest/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so far the only answer that I can fathom and is supported by this [blog](http://icoderaven.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/peek-a-boo/) is that xservers like vnc do not permit "OpenGL calls to the screen" and that [virtualGL](http://www.virtualgl.org/vgldoc/2_1/) is the path forward.

And this other [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/9743/rviz-segfaults-unless-a-monitor-is-connected-any/) means that at least 2 people are using this

I hope there's not a huge gotcha around the corner with vglrun...

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-02**:
With KVM it's possible to pass a real card through and assign it to a particular VM (http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM)